# Discord bot can't play music

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the bot join a vc and play a music from yt and it gives me this error

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

I already installed all libraries that I need, and the only one that doesn't detect is PyNaCl

```
import youtube_dl
import nacl.utils

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx): #join
 user = ctx.message.author
 channel = user.voice_channel
 await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx,url): #play
 server = ctx.message.server
 voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
 player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
 players[server.id] = player
 player.start()
```